# Why import error while using django-templated-email?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am trying to use BradWhittington Django-Templated-Email. I installed it, and added the following lines in the settings.py.

```
from templated_email.backends.vanilla_django import TemplateBackend
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_BACKEND = TemplateBackend
```

When I try to run the server, I get the import error. Even when I use

```
from templated_email import send_templated_mail
```

in the models.py I again get the import error. I am new to django, and I googled for the answer many times. But no luck. What am I missing? The 'Run' window on pycharm shows the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "E:\***\***\***\env1\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" syncdb "E:/***/***/***/***"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:/***/***/***/***\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:/***/***/***/***\***\settings.py", line 17, in <module>
    from templated_email.backends.vanilla_django import TemplateBackend
  File "E:\***\***\***\env1\lib\site-packages\templated_email\__init__.py", line 23
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using virtual environment. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Django-Templated-Email does not support python 3, which you are using.
You can migrate your project to python2, but it's better to find modern alternative to Django-Templated-Email.